# How can I access database using nestjs/typeorm with database name in multiple databases

Tags: express, nestjs, typeorm

```
const defaultOptions = {
  type: 'postgres',
  port: 5432,
  username: 'user',
  password: 'password',
  database: 'db',
  synchronize: true,
};

@Module({
  imports: [
    TypeOrmModule.forRoot({
      ...defaultOptions,
      host: 'user_db_host',
      entities: [User],
    }),
    TypeOrmModule.forRoot({
      ...defaultOptions,
      name: 'albumsConnection1',
      host: 'album_db_host',
      entities: [Album],
    }),
    TypeOrmModule.forRoot({
      ...defaultOptions,
      name: 'albumsConnection2',
      host: 'album_db_host',
      entities: [Album],
    }),
    ...
  ],
})
export class AppModule {}
```

Hi,
I want to send a name parameter to access the DB of the name and get the results for the query.

For example, when I send a

```
{ dbname: 'albumsConnection1' }
```

How can I access specific database with parameter dbname?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to run a raw query in your service with one of the databases defined above, inject the connection using `@InjectConnection()` with connection name as its parameter:

```js
import { Connection } from 'typeorm';
import { InjectConnection } from '@nestjs/typeorm';

@Injectable()
export class FooService {
  constructor(@InjectConnection('albumsConnection1') private connection: Connection) {}

  async doSomeQuery() {
    return this.connection.query('<SOME QUERY>');  // This query will be executed on database 'albumsConnection1'
  }
}
```

Comment: I have a question, If I have 30 databases, I have to create connection to injection?

Answer (score 0):

```
import { InjectConnection } from '@nestjs/typeorm';
import { DataSource, getConnection } from 'typeorm';

@Injectable()
export class FooService{
   constructor(
    @InjectConnection('NameConnection1')
    private dataSource1: DataSource,
    @InjectConnection('NameConnection2')
    private dataSource2: DataSource,
  ) {}
  async doSomeQuery(connection: string) {
    switch (connection){
      case 'Connection1': this.dataSource1.manager.findOne()
    ...
   }
  }
}
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).